# Nutch not working on Windows 10

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, nutch

I'm trying to do crawl with the `Nutch` and on `ElasticSearch` and `MongoDB`. After that, I saw some useful tutorials and SO question/answers as following I can not run the `Nutch`.

[Search Engine with Apache Nutch, MongoDB and Elasticsearch](http://www.aossama.com/search-engine-with-apache-nutch-mongodb-and-elasticsearch/)

[Scraping the Web with Nutch for Elasticsearch](https://qbox.io/blog/scraping-the-web-with-nutch-for-elasticsearch)

And I saw this question:
[nutch-does-not-index-on-elasticsearch-correctly-using-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885025/nutch-does-not-index-on-elasticsearch-correctly-using-mongodb)

I build the Nutch with ant, but when I run the Nutch in command prompt with `.\nutch` command, it does not show anything in Command Prompt and just shows the Nutch file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved by install the `Cygwin`. You need install the Cygwin and install packages in the default.

Comment: Or in other words, Nutch needs Linux environment to run. Hence cygwin helped. Alternatively, you may also install a Linux vm on Virtual Box n try.

Comment: @RamDwivedi Yes, you are right. I installed it in the Ubuntu.